# Batteries for a StarNavigator 90 motorized mount?

Tags: telescope

I was given a StarNavigator 90 (DS-2090) with a motorized mount (Single-arm, motorized Alt-Az) which works with 8 AA batteries. Only issue is that it eats the batteries, so I am wondering what kind of batteries are recommended for motorized mounts?

Also, can I use a 12V battery (such as those gel batteries, or even car battery) to power the mount?

Comment: A stack of 16 rechargeable batteries would seem to be the easiest solution. Chargers usually handle 4 at a time, so you could use 2 chargers if you have little time to charge between two sets of 8.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I bought a DC adapter (12v / 2 Amps) and works perfect! If I need to go to a location where there's no AC plug nearby then I carry the batteries with me but I still can't use it for long periods, i will probably buy an alarm battery or some sort of 12V battery for this.

Comment: I think it's perfectly okay for you to repost your comment as an answer and accept it.